# React Draft Wysiwyg Expand Image OnClick?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-draft-wysiwyg

How would I expand an image when I click it to become fullscreen on React Draft Wysiwyg? I currently use createEntity and AtomicBlockUtils to manually insert the copy pasted image into the editor. Could I put a onClick function anywhere along the way?

Comment: could you share a code sandbox with that implementation?

Answer (score 0):

The solution to this is making a custom function on the editor toolbar that expands the editor textfield itself (change css using className). Create a className in CSS that is essentially `.textfield_on_expand img {width: "whatever you want"; height: "whatever you want}` . Its a really hacky solution and not very elegant but as far as I know the only way to expand.